# Jekyll right align text

Tags: jekyll, text-alignment

How do you right align text in Jekyll?

I have a block of text I want to right align.

If it was HTML, I'd do something like:

```
style="text-align:right;"
```

How can I do that in Markdown with Jekyll?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jekyll 2.0+ uses kramdown as a default markdown converter.

You can declare right align in your css:

```
.right{
     text-align: right;
}
```

Then, simply add after your paragraph:

```
This text is right aligned. {: .right}
```

Comment: You may want to set the direction property instead of text-align

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use HTML tags for that, e.g. `<p style="text-align: right">`. Markdown can align table contents by putting a colon in the separator line (left, right, both ends), but not normal text, AFAIK.

Comment: FWIW, that is why I prefer textile. It can do much more without HTML tags. It doesn't always look like a normal text anymore, but it is, IMO, much more powerful for markup, even more powerful than kramdown or multiMarkdown.

Answer (score 2):

Jekyll supports Textile language, so you can use the [specific tags for paragraphs](http://txstyle.org/doc/2/paragraphs), in your case the tag to align on the right `p>.`.

In the linked page:

```
p>. Aligned right paragraph.
```

Comment: this requires a plugin, ie not out of the box

Answer (score 1):

As we known, Jekyll uses kramdown as a default markdown converter from 2.0+. And It doesn't support the table text alignment now, I think the below can help you.

**1. The first solution is HTML and CSS (for normal block alignment):**

a. using inline style:

```
<p style="text-align: right">Your awesome text</p>
```

b. using outer style:

```
.right {
   text-align: right;
}
```

and

```
<p class="right">Your awesome text</p>
```

or

```
Your awesome text. {: .right}
```

**2. The second solution is Jekyll Plugin (for table alignment):**

> jekyll-spaceship -  *A Jekyll plugin to provide powerful supports for
> table, mathjax, plantuml, emoji, youtube, dailymotion, vimeo, etc.*

https://github.com/jeffreytse/jekyll-spaceship

> **For now, these extended features are provided:**
>
> - Cells spanning multiple columns
> - Cells spanning multiple rows
> - Cells text align separately
> - Table header not required
> - Grouped table header rows or data rows